# Python pandas.dataframe.isin returning unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas

I have encountered this several times where I'm trying to filter a dataframe using a column from another dataframe.  isin incorrectly returns true for every row.  It is probably just a misunderstanding on my part as to how it should work.  Why is it doing this, and is there a better way to code it?

```
#Read the data into a pandas dataframe
ar_data = pd.read_excel('~/data/Accounts-Receivable.xlsx')
ar_data.set_index('customerID', inplace=True)

#randomly select records for 70/30 train/test split
train = ar_data.sample(frac=.7, random_state = 1)
mask = ~ar_data.index.isin(list(train.index))  #why does this return False for every value?
test = ar_data[mask]

ar_data.shape  #returns (2466, 11)
train.shape #(1726, 11)
test.shape #returns (0, 11).  Should return 740 rows!
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kjIC.png)

Comment: Can you provide a example of your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to execute you code with a sample DataFrame and it works:

```
import pandas as pd
ar_data = [[10,20],[11,2],[9,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(ar_data,columns=["1","2"])
df.set_index("1", inplace=True)
train = df.sample(frac=.7, random_state = 1)
mask = ~df.index.isin(list(train.index))
test = df[mask]
train.shape #shape = (2,1)
test.shape #shape = (1,1)
```

The problem you may probably have is that the index you used is not a key, hence there are multiple lines with the same Customer_id.
In fact executing your code with duplicated indexes leads to the bug you encountered.

```
import pandas as pd
    ar_data = [[10,20],[10,2],[10,3]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(ar_data,columns=["1","2"])
    df.set_index("1", inplace=True)
    train = df.sample(frac=.7, random_state = 1)
    mask = ~df.index.isin(list(train.index))
    test = df[mask]
    train.shape #shape = (2,1)
    test.shape  #shape = (0,1)
```

Anyways an easier and faster way to split your dataset would be:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = ar_data
y = ar_data
train, test, _, _ = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1)
```

with that possibility, you can also split the features and the predictions with only one function, and it doesn't rely on the indexes.

Comment: That must be it.  The index is not unique, since the same customerID can have multiple invoices.  I'll try resetting the index and check it again.

Comment: I tried resetting the index, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: I edited the answer and gave you a way to split the dataset with the function train_test_split, which is way easier and faster. If you can give an example of your dataset I can check if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Actually, your first answer was correct.  I was trying to filter with customerID, which was a mistake, since it is not a unique value.  I got the expected results when I used the unique invoice number for the filter.  Thanks.